# Objects are not valid as a React child. Why does it happen?

Tags: reactjs

I try to start [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) official React code example with my code:

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />

        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// my code
const e = new CustomTextInput();
const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(e, root);
```

but I get the error:

```
Invariant Violation  
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, 
updater, textInput, focusTextInput}). If you meant to render a collection of children, 
use an array instead.
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, I did it.

Comment: You still have not put the error code in your question. Edit it so that future visitor of this post may get clarification and help.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, you a right. I apologize. I added my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use:

```
ReactDOM.render(<CustomTextInput />, root);
```

And avoid using:

```
const e = new CustomTextInput(); // delete this
```

---

React accepts element not instance to render:

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a component instance yourself here:

```
const e = new CustomTextInput();
```

You need to let React do it internally and instead pass it a React element:

```
const e = <CustomTextInput/>;
```

that looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "CustomTextInput",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {},
  "_owner": null
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. Also it works too: `const e = React.createElement(CustomTextInput);`.

Comment: @AndreyBushman yup, jsx tags are converted to `React.createElement` calls in order to make the code understandable for browsers.